# Error SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python, eof

I am getting error while running this part of the code. Tried changing the directory and moving folders around to get this to work, but it won't budge.

Input:

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

dataset_root = 'Python/Data/nsl-kdd'

train_file = os.path.join(dataset_root, 'KDDTrain+.txt')
test_file = os.path.join(dataset_root, 'KDDTest+.txt')

header_names = ['duration', 'protocol_type', 'service', 'flag', 'src_bytes', 'dst_bytes', 'land', 'wrong_fragment', 'urgent', 'hot', 'num_failed_logins', 'logged_in', 'num_compromised', 'root_shell', 'su_attempted', 'num_root', 'num_file_creations', 'num_shells', 'num_access_files', 'num_outbound_cmds', 'is_host_login', 'is_guest_login', 'count', 'srv_count', 'serror_rate', 'srv_serror_rate', 'rerror_rate', 'srv_rerror_rate', 'same_srv_rate', 'diff_srv_rate', 'srv_diff_host_rate', 'dst_host_count', 'dst_host_srv_count', 'dst_host_same_srv_rate', 'dst_host_diff_srv_rate', 'dst_host_same_src_port_rate', 'dst_host_srv_diff_host_rate', 'dst_host_serror_rate', 'dst_host_srv_serror_rate', 'dst_host_rerror_rate', 'dst_host_srv_rerror_rate', 'attack_type', 'success_pred']

col_names = np.array(header_names)

nominal_idx = [1, 2, 3]
binary_idx = [6, 11, 13, 14, 20, 21]
numeric_idx = list(set(range(41)).difference(nominal_idx).difference(binary_idx))

nominal_cols = col_names[nominal_idx].tolist()
binary_cols = col_names[binary_idx].tolist()
numeric_cols = col_names[numeric_idx].tolist()

category = defaultdict(list)
category['benign'].append('normal')

with open('Python/Data/nsl-kdd/training_attack_types.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        attack, cat = line.strip().split(' ')
        category[cat].append(attack)
```

Output:

```
  File "<ipython-input-132-87b8f2b05f6e>", line 1
    with open('Python/Data/nsl-kdd/training_attack_types.txt', 'r') as f:
                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I need to be able to get past this error and read the text file.

Text File contains:

```
apache2 dos
back dos
mailbomb dos
processtable dos
snmpgetattack dos
teardrop dos
smurf dos
land dos
neptune dos
pod dos
udpstorm dos
ps u2r
buffer_overflow u2r
perl u2r
rootkit u2r
loadmodule u2r
xterm u2r
sqlattack u2r
httptunnel u2r
ftp_write r2l
guess_passwd r2l
snmpguess r2l
imap r2l
spy r2l
warezclient r2l
warezmaster r2l
multihop r2l
phf r2l
imap r2l
named r2l
sendmail r2l
xlock r2l
xsnoop r2l
worm r2l
nmap probe
ipsweep probe
portsweep probe
satan probe
mscan probe
saint probe
worm probe
```

Comment: Most likely, you have missed a `'` somewhere.

Comment: Just double checked. No changes.

Comment: `Python/Data/nsl-kdd/training_attack_types.txt` Directory path isn't correct

Comment: Did you miss any brackets?

Comment: Works fine to me...

Comment: try to execute it again

Comment: I keep getting the same error, the input that's working for you is still returning unexpected EOF while parsing for me

Comment: @Spaceman what's the text file's content?

Comment: Updated the question with the contents of the txt file @ppwater

Comment: I don't know what's the problem...

Comment: in your loop, print each line and see where it fails

Comment: It fails on the first line @drum

Comment: `with open('training_attack_types.txt', 'r') as f:
  File "<ipython-input-142-7ad9c3bd9ba1>", line 1
    with open('training_attack_types.txt', 'r') as f:
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`

Comment: It appears that you are somehow executing that line by itself (note the "line 1" in the traceback).  The line isn't a complete statement by itself, it needs the rest of the indented block that follows to be meaningful.